# multiple attachment not working with mms intent in htc

Tags: android

I need to send an MMS with multiple attachment to multiple recipients in HTC device,below is my code

```
            ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
                File file = new File(filePaths[i]); 
                Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                files.add(imageUri);
            }

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            sendIntent.putExtra("address","33434;674374763;89998");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",etmsg.getText().toString()); 
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
            sendIntent.setType(mimetype);
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The problem is files are not attaching to the message.Anybody please help to resolve this.

Comment: try using `putParcelableArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);`

Comment: i tried but not working...!!!plz let me know if you have any suggestion